# Why can't I use AND operator when choosing numpy array elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do this:

```
X = U[(U > lims[0] & U < lims[1])]  #U is numpy array
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ha.py", line 19, in <module>
    X = U[(U > lims[0] & U < lims[1])]
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

But

```
 X = U[(U > lims[0])
```

works perfectly.

What is wrong? And how can I elegantly overcome this?

Comment: Try `X = U[(U > lims[0]) & (U < lims[1])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try something like:

```
X = U[(U > lims[0] & U < lims[1])]
```

Numpy thinks that you are trying to perform a bitwise operation. This is because bitwise `&` operation has higher precedence than a conditional `>` operation.

You should try something like:

```
X = U[(U > lims[0]) & (U < lims[1])]
```